# How can I set up a Bitbucket and SonarCloud integration for a Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, continuous-integration, sonarqube, bitbucket

*Disclaimer: I do have almost no knowledge with DevOps, containers and CI/CD pipelines and it's something I'm learning on the fly.*

I currently have a private Xamarin.Forms project hosted on Bitbucket, and I've created a SonarCloud account that I want to use to analyze the code within Bitbucket. From what I was able to gather from the SonarCloud onboarding process I need to setup a build pipeline within Bitbucket.

This is a code snippet of what SonarCloud says that I need to use within the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
image: ************************** # Choose an image matching your project needs

clone:
      depth: full              # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

definitions:
      caches:
            sonar: ~/.sonar/cache  # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build
      steps:
      - step: &build-test-sonarcloud
              name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
              caches:
              - **************************           # See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html
              - sonar
              script:
              - **************************           # Build your project and run
              - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.0.1
      - step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
              name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
              script:
              - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.3

pipelines:                 # More info here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
```

I've read and re-read the https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html article, but I wasn't ablet to gather much information. Seems like a rabbit hole with links to another articles that don't seem like they will be able to get me where I need.

So, a the moment my major doubts are:

- Can a Bitbucket pipeline build Xamarin.Forms projects? (Android and iOS)

  - If so, how can I set up a bitbucket-pipelines.yml in order to allow that?
- If not, should I go to Azure Devops or some other platform that will allow me to do that and integrate with SonarCloud?

I'm already using Visual Studio App Center to build the Android and iOS app (integraged with Bitbucket). But it seems like the AppCenter can't be natively integrated with SonarCloud.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a sample working *bitbucket-pipelines.yml* file for reference

```
image: node:10.15.0 # Choose an image matching your project needs

clone:
  depth: full              # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

definitions:
  caches:
    sonar: ~/.sonar/cache  # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build
  steps:
    - step: &build-test-sonarcloud
        name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
        caches:
          - node         # See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html
          - sonar
        script:
          - npm install
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.0
    - step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
        name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
        script:
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.4

pipelines:                 # More info here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html
  custom: # defines that this can only be triggered manually or by a schedule
    staging: # The name that is displayed in the list in the Bitbucket Cloud GUI
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "Scheduled builds in Pipelines are awesome!"
      - step: 
          name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
          caches:
            - node         # See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html
            - sonar
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.0
      - step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
          name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.4

  branches:
    master:
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
      - step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
```

Pipeline file is used to create a small container in bitbucket infrastructure and runs the code analysis there.

This file provides information regarding

- When all checks should run
- What all checks should be done.
- Configuration of the image and container which will be created to run the pipeline.
- Cache configuration for faster builds.
- Reusable build-level code components like steps etc.

bit bucket docs for reference

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/